# Why would investors invest in an environmentally friendly production of Panna Cotta?

Tags: investing, investment-strategies

I am doing a class presentation and I have created a business plan that will replace the traditional plastic use of Panna Cotta with environmentally friendly materials and now I need to present reasons why would potential investors care about it and why they should care about it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this seems to be a homework question rather than a question about personal finance.

Comment: no, if I get approved I can do it in real life.

Comment: How do you use the dessert as a plastic?

Comment: You might explain what Panna Cotta is.

Answer (score 0):

You said you created a business plan, what is the potential profit of using such a product?  Can it be made cheaper there by giving your product a competitive advantage?  If not, is it projected that the base materials may rise to make the traditional method more expensive?  What about disposing of the more traditional materials used, will that become more expensive?

Without a more profitable product you do not have a "business case" and therefore less likely to attract investors.

Comment: My competite advantage I think is that I can attract a new segment of customers: environment-concious people would be a new customer segment I think. Does this make sense?

Comment: Sure, that can be part of it. You would just need to provide evidence of such.

Comment: I don't understand why your whole judgement of the business case is based on money, why wouldn't investors be interested in a less profitable product if it's better for the environment?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson the question was asked about attracting investors.  As such they would expect profit.  The homework assignment could be answered in  a different way such that environmental concerns where the main focus.

Comment: Yes, expect profit but my point was that they can very well accept a lower profit if other concerns are met and still find it worthwhile to invest.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson There is a name to this investment movement now.  It comes under the guise of Environment, Social, and Governance (ESG).  There is a growing market of investors who will want to see the "return on investment" expressed along these dimensions as well as the purely financial.